Has anyone heard of "lifting diagrams" for matrix operations?
Currently studying colour space conversions for image representation. In my prof's slides, there's something he calls lifting diagrams:

They're just used to show matrix transformations, basically. This example here is showing a transformation from XYZ to RGB (as in the colour space). Intuitively I think they do make sense, but this is the first time I've ever seen them in my life. I tried searching them up on the internet but couldn't find any explanations (even reverse image search didn't return a decent result).
Another example:

Anyone have any idea what, exactly, these things are? I've tried "lifting diagram" (returned images of people lifting heavy objects), "lifting matrix", "lift transform", etc. They aren't mentioned in the textbook at all... is this something my prof just made up?

Have you asked your professor about it?

@Trebor Yeah, he said told me to Google "lifting diagram matrix" and said I could find some related sources, mostly in deep high-level research papers. The stuff I found was super different and not at all helpful.
